# Ruby ri documentation error

Tags: ruby, ri

I have installed Ruby through the RubyInstaller, which didn't include the ri documentation. Then I rebuilt it through rdoc --all --ri. But when I try to use it, I get weird chars like:

```
C:\Ruby>ri Array
←[0m←[1;32mArray < Object←[m

(from ~/.ri)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
←[1;32mInstance methods:←[m

  abbrev, dclone, pretty_print, pretty_print_cycle, shelljoin, to_csv,
  to_yaml, yaml_initialize


C:\Ruby>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ri -f plain Array`. The arrows are escape sequences used to display colors.